# Как хранить информацию, какому полигону какая текстура соответствует в модели?

Tags: android, opengl, java, 3d

Я разрабатываю компьютерную игру для Android. Для этих целей пишу на Java 3D движок основанный на OpenGl ES 2.0. Для загрузки 3D сцены в него используется простой внутренний бинарный формат хранения атрибутов вертексов.
Вида

```
float x,y,z
float u,v;
float u1,v1;
float nx,ny,nz;
int R,G,B,A;
```

Проблема в том как интегрировать в этот формат информацию о том какому полигону принадлежит какая текстура. Если добавить в структуру указатель на текстуру int TextureID тогда файл становится слишком большим так как полигон состоит из 3 вертексов и к тому же нескольким полигонам может соответствовать одинаковая текстура. Я решил обойти гору и создать для каждого файла с вершинами новый файл вида:

```
int TextureID
long Shift
long Length
```

Где shift сдвиг от начала файла с атрибутами вертексов измеряемый в полигонах, а length длина относительно сдвигов указывающая на сколько следующих полигонов нужно наложить эту текстуру. Этот путь лучше чем первый но он плох тем что могут возникнуть осложнения при выгрузки моделей из 3D редактора. Есть ли альтернативные варианты решения этой проблемы? Каким образом хранится подобная информация в других форматах?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше идти не от модели - а от материала.

Я делал так:
 Файлы с описанием материала ( шейдеры + текстуры + другие данные )
 Файлы с моделями ( id материала + вертексы + тест.координаты + карты +...)

То есть если одной модели в редакторе соответствует несколько материалов - то разбивал на несколько моделей.

Все модели для одного материала рисую за один проход.

Отрисовка без частого переключения материала получалась намного быстрее, особенно при большом количестве небольших моделей.

Answer (score 4):

Не выдумывайте велосипед, а уложите ваши данные в SQLite в виде 2-х таблиц:

1. Таблица вертексов или полигонов
2. Таблица текстур

Связка между ними по id текстур, не забудьте проиндексировать по id текстур и полигонов.

Это намного проще и быстрее по скорости, чем ваш доморощеный формат. Тем более как вы правильно сами сказали будут проблемы при выгрузке 3D модели.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно в модели массив вершин (и всех их атрибутов - нормалей, цветов, текстурных координат и так далее) хранится отдельно от массива индексов. Массив индексов как раз и задаёт, как соединять точки в треугольники.
Если Вы создите несколько таких массивов в своей модельке - сможете задавать материал для отдельных её частей.

Материал - это совокупность параметров текстуры, шейдера, освещения(если это обычный рендеринг, конечно, а не какое-нибудь отложенное затенение) и так далее =)

То есть в итоге модель будет примерно такой:

`struct Vertex
{
 float x, y, z;
 float tx, ty;
 float nx, ny, nz;
}
struct Triangle
{
 int a, b, c; //индексы в массиве вершин
}
class Mesh
{
 Vertex[] Vertices;
 Triangle[][] Chunks; //для модели с одним материалом это одномерный массив, если же материалов может быть несколько - первое измерение массива равно их количеству.
}`

Соответственно при рендеринге остаётся только выставить подходящий материал (допустим, номер I) (текущую текстуру, цвета, параметры освещения(установить шейдер и задать юниформы), а потом отрисовать Chunks[I], и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще раз это тоже довольно старый вопрос. Я успел за это время переписать движок на С++ и там все это как нужно сделано.